# Finding a similar matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let two square matrices $A$ and $P$ be given. How to find an invertible matrix $P_1$ so that $P_1^{-1} A P_1 = PA$?

Comment: This is equivalent to finding an invertible matrix $X$ that solves $AX - X(PA) = 0$.  This is a linear system of equations.  More specifically, it is a [Sylvester equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_equation).

Comment: This looks strange. $P_1^{-1}AP_1$ is similar to $A$, while $PA$ most likely isn't. So this is going to be impossible, unless we know something special about $P$ (or impossible at all -- I need to think a little more about this).

Comment: Thank you so much Omm...

Answer (score 1):

> In linear algebra, two $~n\times n~$  matrices $~A~$ and $~P~$ are called **[similar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_similarity)** if there exists an invertible $~n\times n~$ matrix $~P_1~$ such that $$P=P_1^{-1}AP_1$$

So the equality given in the question i.e., $~P_1^{-1} A P_1 = PA~$ is only valid for $~A=I_{n \times n}~$.